# how to merge RDD tuples

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use reduceByKey merge many tuples with same key,
here is the code:

```
val data = Array(DenseMatrix((2.0,1.0,5.0),(4.0,3.0,6.0)),
  DenseMatrix((7.0,8.0,9.0),(10.0,12.0,11.0)))

val init = sc.parallelize(data,2)
//getColumn

def getColumn(v:DenseMatrix[Double]) : Map[Int, IndexedSeq[(Int, Double)]]={
  val r = Random
  val index = 0 to v.size - 1
  def func(x:Int, y:DenseMatrix[Double]):(Int,(Int, Double)) =
  {
    ( x,( r.nextInt(10), y.valueAt(x)))
  }
  val rest = index.map{x=> func(x,v)}.groupBy(x=>x._1).mapValues(x=>x.map(_._2))
  rest

}
val out= init.flatMap{ v=> getColumn(v) }
val reduceOutput = tmp.reduceByKey(_++_)

val out2 = out.map{case(k,v)=>k}.collect()  // keys here are not I want
```

here is two pic, the first one is the [key,value] pairs I thought it would be, the second one shows the real keys ,they are not I want,so the ouput is not right.

What should I do?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What result do you want exactly ?

Comment: You don't want tuples as the output, since you don't know how long they will be, so it will be very difficult to write code to do anything with them.. What do you really want?

Comment: `reduceByKey` seems fine, the tuples are merged into one vector but what are trying to achieve by `val out2 = out.map{case(k,v)=>k}.collect()`? Please clarify?

Comment: `val out2 = out.map{case(k,v)=>k}.collect()`  is a test ,I just wanna make a compare of pic and pic2. Becsuse I thought the keys of  `val out= init.flatMap{ v=> getColumn(v) }` are (2,5,0,9,1,2,3,6,1,9,7,3) (check pic1), but in fact the keys are pic2. Well ,I have known the problem, since `"rest"` is `IndexedSeq( Int, Double )`，and IndexedSeq is not a serializable type, so when we use it with map or flatmap or reduceByKey, it can cause OS  racing , so we better  use **" serializable type  "**. @Ramesh Maharjan